# Threading in Realm - Clean Code Architecture

Tags: java, android, realm, rx-java, dagger-2

I'm using the Clean Code Architecture on Android and Dagger with Realm, but I can't find a way to make it work together.
Bottom line is, I'm always getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
```

[FetchItemsRepo](https://github.com/leonardo2204/materialnotes/blob/bug_thread_realm/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/materialnotes/data/repository/ItemsRepositoryImpl.java):

```
 @Override
    public Observable<List<Item>> fetchAllItems() {
        final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build());

        final RealmQuery<Checkboxes> queryCheck = realm.where(Checkboxes.class);
        final RealmQuery<ImageItem> queryImage = realm.where(ImageItem.class);

        return queryCheck.findAll()
                .asObservable()
                .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<Checkboxes>, Observable<RealmResults<ImageItem>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<RealmResults<ImageItem>> call(RealmResults<Checkboxes> checkboxes) {
                        for (Checkboxes checks : checkboxes)
                            items.add(checks);

                        return queryImage.findAll().asObservable();
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<ImageItem>, Observable<List<Item>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<Item>> call(RealmResults<ImageItem> imageItems) {
                        for (ImageItem images : imageItems)
                            items.add(images);

                        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Item>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Item>> subscriber) {
                                subscriber.onNext(items);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
```

[GetItemsUseCase](https://github.com/leonardo2204/materialnotes/blob/bug_thread_realm/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/materialnotes/domain/interactor/GetItemsUseCase.java):

```
public class GetItemsUseCase extends UseCase {

    private final ItemsRepository itemsRepository;

    @Inject
    public GetItemsUseCase(ItemsRepository itemsRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread) {
        super(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread);
        this.itemsRepository = itemsRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {
        return this.itemsRepository.fetchAllItems();
    }
}
```

And the [UseCase](https://github.com/leonardo2204/materialnotes/blob/bug_thread_realm/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/materialnotes/domain/interactor/UseCase.java):

```
public void execute(Subscriber UseCaseSubscriber) {
        this.subscription = this.buildUseCaseObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler())
                .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber);
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is any way to make Realm works with this pattern.
The entire project is open-sourced on my GitHub: https://github.com/leonardo2204/materialnotes/tree/bug_thread_realm

Edit:

```
Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
 at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(BaseRealm.java:456)
 at io.realm.RealmResults.addChangeListener(RealmResults.java:926)
 at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$5.call(RealmObservableFactory.java:147)
 at io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$5.call(RealmObservableFactory.java:131)
 at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:9860)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
 at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:9860)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
 at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
 at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:9860)
 at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
 at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
 at rx.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:104)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: With realm, every thread needs its own realm instance. You can't pass realm instance or objects from thread to thread. Also make sure to shutdown a realm instance when exiting the thread.

Comment: So perhaps the problem is I'm fetching the objects in a Thread (from the ThreadPoolExecutor) and sending it over to the UI Thread ?

Comment: Now you can figure out how to fix that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your Realm objects detached in your RealmResults using `realm.copyFromRealm()`.

EDIT: it says your problem is that your Realm instance is not on the same thread as where you're subscribing, which is fair if you are subscribing on `Schedulers.from(threadExecutor)` but you're initializing this query on the UI thread.

`asObservable()` won't work on a background thread anyways, only on the UI thread - because it needs to add a change listener, and the change listener needs the main looper to receive updates.

Honestly at this rate you could either do this (and lose auto-updates):

```
    final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
         realm = Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build());

        final RealmQuery<Checkboxes> queryCheck = realm.where(Checkboxes.class);
        final RealmQuery<ImageItem> queryImage = realm.where(ImageItem.class);

        RealmResults<Checkboxes> checkBoxes = queryCheck.findAll();
        RealmResults<ImageItem> imageItems = queryImage.findAll();

        for(Checkboxes checkbox : checkBoxes) {
            items.add(realm.copyFromRealm(checkbox));
        }
        for(ImageItem checkbox : checkBoxes) {
            items.add(realm.copyFromRealm(checkbox));
        }
    } finally {
        if(realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
    return Observable.just(items);
```

Or just rethink the way you're doing this entirely, because the optimal solution would be to use `findAllAsync()` from the UI thread, and if you could obtain both lists in one result list.

EDIT2: It's worth noting that the intended usage of `asObservable()` is to replace `addChangeListener()`, but you can only "observe changes" to the Realm on looper threads (typically the UI thread).

So the intended usage of `asObservable()` is the following

```
private Subscription readFromEditText() {
    return RxTextView.textChanges(editText).switchMap(charSequence -> {
        String selectedName = charSequence.toString();
        RealmQuery<Dog> query = realm.where(Dog.class);
        if(selectedName != null && !"".equals(selectedName)) {
            query = query.contains(DogFields.NAME, selectedName, Case.INSENSITIVE);
        }
        return query.findAllSortedAsync(DogFields.NAME)
                    .asObservable();
    }).filter(RealmResults::isLoaded) //filter async realm query
      .subscribe(dogs -> adapter.updateData(dogs));
}
```

Comment: Where is it exactly, please ?

Comment: I'm on version 1.1.0, I don't have the copyFromRealm() function.

Comment: Actually I found it, under realm.copyFromRealm(), but it didn't solve my problem. The function never reaches the flapMap, I get the error before....

Comment: Oh. It's a method of the Realm instance. My mistake :  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyFromRealm-E-

Comment: In that case you kinda shoulda shared a stack trace.

Comment: I see your point, but what would be the best approach on a MVP scenario ?? I mean, inside a Presenter, not on the Fragment/Activity ?

Comment: While I didn't move it from the view per say in this example, this is how I think `.asObservable()` is meant to be used with Realm: https://github.com/Zhuinden/rx-realm-recyclerview-experiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/rxrealm/path/dog/DogView.java#L146-L165

Comment: That did the trick, I'll try to get a deep understanding on the platform. Thanks you so much for your help !